# git file COMMIT_EDITMSG is set readonly after each commit

Tags: git, file-permissions, read-only, commit

I'm using git on Windows 7 (my user is in the local admin group) with my dev project, but everytime I commit changes, the file `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` change too :
It's content is replaced with the last commit msg (which is fine)
It's property changed to `readonly`.

Because of this property change, the next commit I'll make will return an error "Permission denied"...

As I saw in other posts, I tried to delete both files:
- `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`
- `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG.bak`

Or I also tried to just uncheck the `readonly` property manually, but the problem is still there after the next successful commit...

What should I do to repair this problem ?

Notice that I've setted a `prepare-commit-msg` hook which can perhaps be the problem ? Hook content below :

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name this script "prepare-commit-msg"
# This script will prefix every commit msg with the branch name in brackets,
# except if we are on non working branch like develop or master.
# The branch name pattern is : {category}/{issue-nb}_{work-description}

if [ -z "$BRANCHES_TO_SKIP" ]; then
  BRANCHES_TO_SKIP=(master develop)
fi

# Find current branch name
BRANCH_NAME=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
# Remove category before slash (included)
BRANCH_NAME="${BRANCH_NAME##*/}"
# Remove description after first underscore (included)
BRANCH_NAME="${BRANCH_NAME%_*}"


# Check if the branch is excluded
BRANCH_EXCLUDED=$(printf "%s\n" "${BRANCHES_TO_SKIP[@]}" | grep -c "^$BRANCH_NAME$")
BRANCH_IN_COMMIT=$(grep -c "\[$BRANCH_NAME\]" $1)

# Check if branch name is not null, if the current branch is not an excluded one, and if the branch name is already in the commit msg
if [ -n "$BRANCH_NAME" ] && ! [[ $BRANCH_EXCLUDED -eq 1 ]] && ! [[ $BRANCH_IN_COMMIT -ge 1 ]]; then 
  # Add brackets around branch name and Prefix passed msg with it
  sed -i.bak -e "1s/^/[$BRANCH_NAME] /" $1
fi
```